# Scala: Mocking an enclosed object

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

I'm trying to write a unit test for object A, which uses some methods from another object B. How do I override B's methods?

A.scala

```
import somePackage.B

object A { // This is to be tested
def fun1(str: String) = {
   val str2 = processStr(str) //Say str2 = "sahil"
   B.doSomething(str2)  // This is to be overridden
}
```

B.scala

```
object B {
  private def doSomething(str: String) = {
   // do something
    "abc"
  }
}
```

ATest.scala

```
class ATest extends FlatSpec {
    it "should return sahil instead of abc" in {
        // Do something to override B.doSomething
        A.fun1("someString") 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a design failure at architectural level and a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should not use **singleton** without a (really) compelling reason.

Instead for both testability and modularity, consider injecting your dependency explicitly (right now you are declaring the dependency between `A` and `B` *implicitly* through singleton).

```
class A(b: B) {
  def fun1(str: String) = b.doSomething(str)
}

class B {
  def doSomething(str: String) = "abc"
}

class ATest extends FlatSpec {
  it "" in {
    val b = new B { override def doSomething(str: String) = "testing..." }
    val a = new A(b)
    a.fun1("someString") must beEqual "testing..."
  }
}
```

Comment: Haha, Thanks for the link to the XY problem!

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this. Without using DI the only thing that comes to my mind is to overload fun1 with package-private modifier:

```
package somePackage
import somePackage.B

object A {

  def fun1(str: String) = fun1(B.doSomething)

  private[somePackage] def fun1(str: String, f: (String) => String) = {
    val str2 = processStr(str)
    f(str2)
  }

}
```

Then you can pass any mock you would like into fun1